# activate a p:ajax event where using right click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am working with `JSF` and `Primefaces 5.2` ad i noticed that when you use a `commandLink` and add the event `onclick` with p:ajax like that you make a sort of selection on it

```
<h:commandLink  id="commandLink">
<p:ajax event="click"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

my question is : i am working with javascript and what i want to do is when the user right click on the `commandLink` it activate the `p:ajax` specification (making the selection effect)

**myJavascript**

```
document.oncontextmenu = function () { };
```

I know that my question is a little bit weird thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `contextmenu` event to your `commandLink` element like so.

```
var commandLink = document.getElementById('commandLink');

commandLink.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (event) {
  alert('commandLink was right clicked');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/wisonusivi/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i didn't understand how it can help me to activate the same effect as the `p:ajax`

Comment: What does `p:ajax` do? I'm not familiar with `JSF` or `Primefaces`, but this code will be executed when a user right clicks on `<h:commandLink>`.

Comment: when you use the `onclick` event it create the effect of selection it is the same in your windows explorer effect when you click on a folder and i want to make the same with `right click`

Comment: I'm still not clear as to what you are referring to. Please provide a link to a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) so I can see what you mean.

Comment: ok i will as soon as possible just an other question i don't think that the `var commandLink = document.getElementById('commandLink');` work because it doesn't show the alert

Comment: the problem is even if i use use your method it doesn't work